# Laravel View Composer "Cannot use object of type Closure as array"

Tags: php, laravel

I am using an array for my view composer and it throws this error when I try to view the page **`Cannot use object of type Closure as array`**.

I tried using eloquent instead for the variable but that didn't end up working because that is not how it is supposed to be structured the way I am using them. I've also tried creating a function within the `$view->with()`variable.

```
public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('configurable', function() {
            $configurables = Cache::rememberForever('configurables', function() {
                return Configurables::all();
            });
            $configurable = [];
            foreach($configurables as $key) {
                $configurable[$key->slug] = [
                    'value' => $key->value
                ];
            }

            return $configurable;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the full error and the line where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `with()` method expects a value, not a function (closure). You can refactor your code like following:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{

        $configurables = Cache::rememberForever('configurables', function() {
            return Configurables::all();
        });

        $configurable = [];

        foreach($configurables as $key) {
            $configurable[$key->slug] = [
                'value' => $key->value
            ];
        }

       $view->with('configurable', $configurable);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will check to see if it works this morning

Comment: Thank you that was the fix!

Comment: Glad it helped :)